# Hibernate: OR in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, sql-order-by

Consider this situation: I have a table of lessons, every lesson has a day of week (0-6; not a date) and a lesson hour when the lesson holds (not the time, but rather sequence number of the lesson in a day, ie. 1 to 10). And I need to find the first lesson after specific day and hour.

Given these lessons (day-hour): monday-5, wednesday-2, friday-1, friday-3.

For a lesson after wednesday-2 I would receive friday-1, friday-3 after friday-2, monday-5 after friday-5, and so on. So it "overflows" over the end of the week.

In one project where I used Hibernate HQL I solved it with this query:

```
SELECT l FROM Lesson l
ORDER BY (l.day > :day OR (l.day = :day AND l.hour >= :hour)),
l.day DESC, l.hour DESC LIMIT 1
```

Surprisingly, this really worked, although I really don't remember how I came up with it. It's a real magic.

But now I need to do it in another project (this time Java EE web-based) where I use JPA, and Hibernate too. Thinking it'll work the same (using Hibernate and HQL again), it throws exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: OR near line 1, column 101
```

which points to that OR in ORDER BY clause.

I know that OR inside ORDER BY is really awkward but it did work, so I thought it is OK. But now I don't know what to do with it. Could it be because of different Hibernate version or because of the use of JPA? (I'm not sure about version, both are Hibernate 3). Both databases were MySQL.

Thanks for any help (or providing another query which will work as specified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer, I really don't know that much about Hibernate so I'm going to assume that `l.day > :day` in your `order by` "returns" a boolean.

I'm a little surprised that this worked at all; I would use a [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement in this situation so that it's abundantly clear what's going on:

```
SELECT <columns>
  FROM Lesson l
 ORDER BY case when (l.day > :day OR (l.day = :day AND l.hour >= :hour)) then 1
               else 0 end DESC
        , l.day DESC
        , l.hour DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! I tried it with IF() before I asked but that didn't work either throwing NullPointerException somewhere inside Hibernate, weird.